# Auto restore/sync in-app purchases in Newsstand app prior to iOS 9 and iTunes password prompt issue

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes-store, newsstand-kit

I have recently started developing Newsstand application and need to deal with the restoration of in-app purchases. There are cases resported that some users made unwanted "duplicated" purchase in the following situation:

There are two kinds of purchases in the app:
1. One year subscription which will allow users to have access to all magazines issued within the subscription period
2. Single specific issue purchase, which will allow users to buy specific issue they would like to access to

And the problem arises when:

1. User made an one year subscription
2. User install the Newsstand app on another device/re-stall after deleting the app
3. User purchase single issue which should be included in the subscription

In step 3, the user should have "owned" the issue he wanted to purchase and the purchase option for that specific issue will not be available, but since he/she didn't perform a restore, the app does not know the user has an active subscription which includes the targeted issue, as a result the user is charged for the specific issue while he/she should not be.

To deal with this, I am thinking of prompting the user to perform a restore upon first launch of the app after installation, but there are a few questions I would like to clearify and couldn't find any reference or documentation:

1. I was told that prior to iOS 9, the Newsstand app (the one which will have all contents of newsstand applications' contents showed up as a bookshelf) could auto sync/restore purchased contents of the iTunes account logged-in on the device, i.e. after installation and launch the app, the user will have all of his previous purchase there without manually performing a restore. Is this real and is there any documentation regarding this? Or is this related to certain settings related to AppStore's auto-download, etc? This is reported by one of the user and he claimed that he is very sure that he got all the contents without manually restoration after installing the app as he tested this on his iOS 8 device. I ran out of luck in finding and proofing this as I do not have any physical device with iOS 8 or before, and the simulator does not support purchase related API.
2. When performing restoration, under what circumstances the user will be prompted for password input? As sometimes I would proceed to restoration directly without password input, is this related to time passed since last password input?

Thanks!